# Get current directory from setup project

Tags: c#

I create a setup project in Install Shield Limited Edition Visual Studio for Windows 7.

In this project I need to run a C# application as Customer Action During Installation. In this C# application I need path from where setup project runs.
I tried to use `GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName` or `GetExecutionAssembly()`. Location or `Envirement.CurrentDirectory`. All this functions work from  the application. But if I add this program to set up project as Custom Action During installation I get path to `C:\Windows.`

How can I get real path ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you have to added the custom installer to your install project in the Custom Actions pain. Select the Install action and set the `CustomActionData` property to:

```
/targetdir="[TARGETDIR]\"
```

Then you can access the path like this:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class CustomInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        base.Install(stateSaver);
        string path = this.Context.Parameters["targetdir"]; 
        // Do something with path.
    } 
}
```

more  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer(v=vs.90).aspx

if you get any issue let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can get application directory

```
string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

or

```
string directory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

or

```
string directory = Thread.GetDomain().BaseDirectory;
```